# why does it copy into memory?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

Let's say I have the following..

```
contract D {
    
    function again(uint256[3] memory bla) external  returns(uint) {
        return bla[0];
    }
}


contract A { 
    
    function test(D f, uint256[3] memory haha) external  returns (uint) {
        return f.again(haha);
    }
    
   
}
```

We call `test`. The very first thing that happens is `haha` gets copied into memory from `calldata`. Now, before calling `f.again(haha)`, it gets copied into memory again. Why is this step necessary ? `haha` was already in memory, so why copy it again ? Also, the `again` function receives data in calldata and uses completelly new memory.

Comment: You can replace `uint[3] memory bla` and `uint[3] memory haha` to `uint[3] calldata ...`. The compiler copies it since you wrote that the array is in memory.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. When I called `test` function,  it copied array from calldata to memory. now, before calling `f.again(haha)` , it copies the array again, even though array was already in memory. Why is the second copy needed ? after this, when it calls `again`, it will copy the array into memory again but for contract D. The question is, why does it copy before calling `f.again`

Comment: Because it's an external call. Actually my older comment was incorrect. There would be a copy even when both the arguments are in `calldata`. Because the `call` opcode needs its input in memory. So I think using `memory` or `calldata` in your `test` function probably doesn't make any difference, gas wise. However, changing to `calldata` in `again` should be cheaper.

Comment: I think it still should make sense to use calldata in `test`, because if you use `memory`, you would have 2 copies , before calling `again`, but if you use `calldata`, you would have only 1 copy

Comment: If you use `memory` then there would be the copies: `calldata -> memory -> call-opcode`. The same remains even when you use `calldata`.

Comment: if we use `calldata`, we can have `calldata` -> `call-opcode`. Can't we ?

Comment: No. If you look [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/yul.html#evm-dialect), `call` opcode needs its input from memory. So `calldata -> memory` is a must.

Comment: I still don't get something. I get that `call` opcode needs data to be in memory, but if `test` function's parameter was memory, it means it was copied into memory already. So `call` can use that data already for `again` function, but it still uses copy again before calling `again`.

Comment: I think, I was right. You said the following - `using memory or calldata in your test function probably doesn't make any difference, gas wise.`. But it actually makes a difference by 330 gas. I can't test how many times the copying happens if I specify `calldata` in `test` function, since there's a bug in remix so I can't follow opcode sequences and all that, but gas difference makes me believe that copying would happen only one time if `calldata` is used in `test`.

Comment: Is that difference with the optimizer enabled?

Comment: yes,  but if you disable optimizer, the difference becomes 353. So, I think what I said is correct. There's no other explanation. Would be good to be able to test this in remix, but somehow they have a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119080/discussion-between-hrkrshnn-and-nika-kurashvili).

Comment: When optimizations are disabled solc is very simple it only translates solidity to required output without trying to optimize. For example since f.again() is a function call it tries to encode input parameters (just haha) without realizing it isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes but optimization does not make any real difference here in terms of copying into memory